# Perform a Realm Migration that adds primary key

Tags: swift, primary-key, database-migration, realm

Within Realm how do you perform a Migration that adds the `Primary Key` function to a property, when using Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was previously answered for Realm Objective-C here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29417579/599344

Essentially, if you're promoting a property to a primary key, and the property already has a unique value per object, you don't need to do anything special aside from running a normal migration.

If your new primary key property does have duplicate entries, then you'll need to change their values to something unique inside the migration block.